# How to get all image files in storage

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to implement something like facebook's image picker with scans the whole device for photos and lets you choose one or multiple.

How do I get all the photos in one device with flutter without knowing the actual directory?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Image Picker plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin for Flutter for picking images from the image library, and taking new pictures with the camera. For Android, this should work out of the box while for [iOS a slight tweaking is required](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#installation).

Also don't forget to add read / write permissions in your
`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Don't forget to grant `Storage` permissions to your app, manually or by this plugin [simple_permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions)

If you're looking to retrieve all image files at once without using Image Picker, you can use the package [Flutter_File_Manager](https://github.com/Eagle6789/flutter_file_manager) and alter the `absolute_paths` to retrieve only image files (*.jpg, *.png, *.bmp, *.tiff, *.gif)
Again, don't forget to add `uses-permissions` like above in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: That plugin just creates an other activity and lets you pick photos form gallery. what I want to get are the photos, not through gallery but just their uri and data.

Comment: Did you tried using Flutter_File_Mangaer as mentioned above?

Comment: The second one will give you both their path and the file. And If I'm that'd be exactly what you' want.